# PHP - Only run a search if a dropdown value is chosen

Tags: php, if-statement, search

I have a search on a site which I only want to display any results if something has been entered into one of the fields. I'm not really a php person so the best I could do was by adding this before the search:

```
<?php code on how to get the listings ... 

if ($search_location != "" || $search_keywords != ""  ) {

... code on how to display the listings.} ?>
```

As far as I understand this will only display the results if either the location or keywords are not empty. Works well so far.

My problem: there is also a dropdown to select a category ... I tried adding this like:

```
if ($search_location != "" || $search_keywords != "" || $search_categories != ""  ) {
```

But the search doesn't work if you only choose a category you have to enter in one of the other fields also, so I am assuming this was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `AND` (which is `&&` in php):

```
if (($search_location != "" || $search_keywords != "") && $search_categories != ""  ) {
//                                                     ^ here
```

Which means:

> provide (`search_location` or `search_keywords`) and `search_categories`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want you to be able to fill in only one of any three. Either location, keyword or category, but the code I tried means you need to fill in at least one of location or keywords for the category one to filter. Hope this is clearer :)

Comment: If you need any of three then your original code is fine.

Comment: That's what I thought, but its not working. The search is run by Ajax, do you think that is causing the problem. Oh, another thing ... probably should have mentioned, its a dynamic dropdown which depends on categories added by users.

Comment: Ok, got there in the end.
I had to use 

    !empty($search_categories) )

I don't know why `!empty` works and `!= ""` didn't but it's all good so I can't complain.

Thanks for the help.
Liz.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer I got incase any one else needs it.

I had to use `!empty` like -

```
if ($search_location != "" || $search_keywords != "" || !empty($search_categories) ) {
```

I don't know why `!empty` works and `!= ""` doesn't, still learning.

Thanks.
Liz.